# UIDatePicker set minimum and maximum time

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I've got a `UIDatePicker` with the time only and I need a possibility to set the minimum and the maximum hour is showed. For example, I need it to start at 6 hours and finish at 15 hrs. Is it possible to perform this with `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no official way to achieve this when using UIDatePicker as a count down timer. However, you could subclass UIPickerView - have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023356/how-can-i-set-the-uidatepickermodecountdowntimers-maximum-time/40969597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for my problem, the answer with `maximumDate` and `minimumDate` isn't what I am looking for. Maybe my solution is not that clear and right, but it worked great for me.
I have changed the `UIDatePicker` with `UIPickerView`, wrote a separate delegate for it:

```
@interface CHMinutesPickerDelegate () <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *minutesArray;

@end

@implementation CHMinutesPickerDelegate

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:       (NSInteger)component {
    return [self.minutesArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.minutesArray objectAtIndex: row];
}

- (NSArray *)minutesArray {
    if (!_minutesArray) {
        NSMutableArray *temporaryMinutesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                [temporaryMinutesArray addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i%i", i, j * 5]];
            }
        }
    _minutesArray = temporaryMinutesArray;
}
    return _minutesArray;
}
```

The `minutesArray` returns array of: { "05", "10"... etc}. It is an example for custom minutes picker, you can write the same thing for hour or etc, choosing your own maximum and minimum value. This worked nice for me.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use this function to retrieve the minimum and maximum date

```
func getTimeIntervalForDate()->(min : Date, max : Date){

let calendar = Calendar.current
var minDateComponent = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date())
minDateComponent.hour = 09 // Start time


let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mma"
let minDate = calendar.date(from: minDateComponent)
print(" min date : \(formatter.string(from: minDate!))")

var maxDateComponent = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: date)
maxDateComponent.hour = 17 //EndTime



let maxDate = calendar.date(from: maxDateComponent)
print(" max date : \(formatter.string(from: maxDate!))")



return (minDate!,maxDate!)
}
```

2) Assign these dated to your pickerview

```
func createPickerView(textField : UITextField, pickerView : UIDatePicker){
    pickerView.datePickerMode = .time
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.inputView = pickerView
    let dates = getTimeIntervalForDate()

    pickerView.minimumDate = dates.min
    pickerView.maximumDate = dates.max
    pickerView.minuteInterval = 30
    pickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}
```

**That's it :)**

Comment: this does not work as expected. DatePicker when in Time mode will still let you pick the time past dates.min.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
datePicker.maximumDate = myMaxDate;
datePicker. minimumDate = myMinDate;
```

Where myMaxDate and myMinDate are `NSDate` objects

Comment: But the hard part is coming up with proper values for `myMaxDate` and `myMinDate` so the time range does what is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't apply if the UIDatePicker is set to UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer (Obj-C) or UIDatePicker.Mode.countDownTimer (Swift).